# Is recall a relatively meaningless metric in a balanced dataset?

Tags: precision-recall, metric

Just looking for a sanity check here.

Leaving aside precision, is talking about the recall of a binary classification algorithm sensible where 50% of the cases presented to it are positive and 50% are negative. Can it be a useful metric in these specific circumstances?

Comment: Absolutely it can.  If you're building a decision rule for which is is very important that you capture all of your positive cases correctly, recall is a very important metric.  The importance of these metrics has very little to do with the qualities of your data, and much more to do with the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely it can. If you're building a decision rule for which is is very important that you capture all of your positive cases correctly, recall is a very important metric. The importance of these metrics has very little to do with the qualities of your data, and much more to do with the problem you are trying to solve.

Note: Converting this from a comment so it is not listed as unanswered.